# Python Subprocess adds extra quotes to my shell arguments

Tags: python, linux, tcp, subprocess, wireshark

### Expected Behavior

Under normal circumstances, I can issue `tshark -E separator='@'` under linux<sup>See Note A</sup> and force it to display fields separated by `@`, as shown below...

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$ tshark -r scp_test.pcap -e frame.number -e ip.src_host -e tcp.srcport -E separator='@' -T fields tcp | less
1@192.168.12.236@33088
2@192.168.12.238@22
3@192.168.12.236@33088
...
```

### Unexpected Behavior

Likewise, I thought I would run the same command through `subprocess.Popen()`, columnify, and colorize based on some analysis... all my analysis depends on the output being separated by `@` when I run the script... however, my script is *not* using `@`... instead, it uses a single-quote; I am not sure I understand why this is happening.

**Script**

```
import subprocess
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1].strip()
fields = ['frame_num', 'IP Src', 'TCP Src']
sep = '@'
cmd = r"""tshark -r %s -e frame.number -e ip.src_host -e tcp.srcport -E separator='%s' -T fields tcp""" % (filename, sep)

subcmd = cmd.split(' ')
lines = subprocess.Popen(subcmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
for line in lines.communicate()[0].split('\n'):
    print line
```

**Results**

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$ python analyze.py scp_test.pcap | less
1'192.168.12.236'33088
2'192.168.12.238'22
3'192.168.12.236'33088
4'192.168.12.238'22
5'192.168.12.236'33088
6'192.168.12.236'33088
7'192.168.12.238'22
8'192.168.12.236'33088
```

It seemingly does not matter whether I assign `sep` using any of the following...

- `sep = '@'`
- `sep = '\@'`
- `sep = re.escape('@')  # Desperation attempt ;-)`

### Question

Can someone explain:

1. Why my output is not separated with `@` in the script above.
2. How I can fix the script using `subprocess`<sup>See Note B</sup>?

---

### End-Notes

**Note A.**  System information:

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$ uname -a
Linux hotcoffee 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 21:35:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$
```

**Note B.** Answers using `os.system()` or `os.popen()` are not what I'm looking for

Comment: your Python code is sending @, I'm willing to bet. have you checked with strace?

Comment: +1 for a fun challenge. now to get back to *my* work :^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tshark is taking the `'` from `'%s'`. don't use the single-quotes:

```
cmd = r"tshark -r %s -e frame.number -e ip.src_host -e tcp.srcport -E separator=%s -T fields tcp" % (filename, sep)
```

when you ran it from the command line, Bash stripped the single-quotes off and tshark didn't see them.